# Trouble configuring xDebug in WAMP for Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, wamp, xdebug

Hellow, everyone!

I trying to configure xDebug in WAMP for debug in VS Code, but I got some trouble. XDebug is already include in my WAMP build. So, in `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.37\bin\php.ini` I have these settings:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="c:/wamp64/bin/php/php7.2.14/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.6.1-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = on
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir ="c:/wamp64/tmp"
xdebug.show_local_vars=0
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

In VS code I added this configuration:

```
"type": "php",
"request": "launch",
"name": "listen for XDebug",
"port": 9000
```

But `phpinfo()` still says:

```
Debug Build: no
```

And in VS code, when I start debug with my configuration, breakpoints didn't work. So, what am I doing wrong?

I am on the following versions:

> ```
> Operating system - Windows 10
> WAMP version - 3.1.7 - 64 bit
> Apache - 2.4.37
> PHP - 7.2.14
> ```

Comment: *"Debug Build: no"* This has nothing to do with Xdebug / debugging your PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this settings in php.ini solve the problem:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```